# Need Docusign API Endpoint

Tags: docusignapi

The docs https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html do not work.  I've spent at least 2 hours trying to get these instructions to work.  Either your instructions are wrong, or they have a bug on their site.

I opened a case with support 4 days ago, but they have not responded.  I am on a time crunch to get this going.  Does anyone know how to get this url.

Here is my C# code:

```
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://www.docusign.net/restapi");
    DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
    DocuSignHeader myHeader = new DocuSignHeader()
    {
    Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocuSignUsername"],
    Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocuSignPassword"],
    IntegratorKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocuSignIntegratorKey"],
    };
    DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myHeader));
    AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
    LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
    LoginAccount myAccount = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0];
.. create envelope here..
   EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(GetBasePath(myAccount.BaseUrl));
   EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(myAccount.AccountId, envDef);
```

The purpose of GetBasePath() is to strip off everything after 'restapi', so the url is correct.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and what error you are getting

Comment: I used this example:$ curl -i -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication:
              { "Username":"developer@example.com",
                "Password":"S3cre+p455w0Rd",
                "IntegratorKey":"230546a7-9c55-40ad-8fbf-af205d5494ad" }'\
          https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

I put in the same credentials I use to log into production.  I changed the url to https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

But I am getting authentication errors.

Comment: I added my C# code also.  Fiddler keeps showing a 401 authorization error.  I have literally spent more than a dozen ours trying to get this to work in production, and it won't work.  It worked fine in sandbox.

Comment: I cannot find your IK 230546a7-9c55-40ad-8fbf-af205d5494ad in the backend, can you please check if you can find this integrator Key in your Admin console?

Comment: You IK will work in PROD once IK is promoted to Prod https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-API-Go-Live-Process-FAQ https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-go-live-process-now-automated/, is your IK promoted to PROD?

Comment: Yes, my code is promoted to prod.  '230546a7-9c55-40ad-8fbf-af205d5494ad' is NOT my integrator key, that is the sample in your documentation.  I didn't know if it was a security violation to report my actual key.

In other news, I found a work around that fixes the problem.  So perhaps this will help find out what the real problem is.

Since I was getting a 401 on the Envelope call, I started thinking that maybe a header is missing.  I added the following line of code right after the Evenlope API, and now it works fine.

Comment: envelopesApi.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myHeader));

Comment: But it does warn me that is deprecated, and I should do it in config.  But I AM already doing it in config.

Answer (score 2):

The DocuSign live production system has multiple account sub-domains as opposed to the demo system which only uses `demo`.  For instance, in production the possible sites are `www`, `na2`, `na3`, `eu`.

Your integration code needs to parse the sub-domain of the `baseUrl` that is returned from your authentication request and re-configure the `apiClient` with that new sub-domain.

It looks like you are using a DocuSign SDK, there's a note in the readme that explains this:

---

**Authentication**

Service Integrations that use Legacy Header Authentication

(Legacy Header Authentication uses the X-DocuSign-Authentication header.)

Use the Authentication: login method to retrieve the account number and the baseUrl for the account. The url for the login method is www.docusign.net for production and demo.docusign.net for the developer sandbox. The baseUrl field is part of the loginAccount object. See the docs and the loginAccount object

The baseUrl for the selected account, in production, will start with na1, na2, na3, eu1, or something else. Use the baseUrl that is returned to create the basePath (see the next step.) Use the basePath for all of your subsequent API calls.

As returned by login method, the baseUrl includes the API version and account id. Split the string to obtain the basePath, just the server name and api name. Eg, you will receive https://na1.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123123123. You want just https://na1.docusign.net/restapi
Instantiate the SDK using the basePath. Eg ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);

Set the authentication header as shown in the examples by using Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader

Reference:  [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

---

**Code Sample**

Here is the corresponding C# code to do exactly what is mentioned above (ie strip the sub-domain of the baseUrl and re-configure the apiClient):

```
// Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
string[] separatingStrings = { "/v2" };
apiClient = new ApiClient(loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl.Split(separatingStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
```