# baseUrl for Prod Docusign Rest C# client

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have been using "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi" as base url for Docusign C# Rest Client, and it has been working fine.
I have just upgraded my integrator key to Prod. Now when I use "https://www.docusign.net/restapi" it shows "Partnet Authentication Failes". Although I am using correct Username, Password and Integrator key.

For Demo: var client = new EnvelopesApi("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
For Prod: var client = new EnvelopesApi("https://www.docusign.net/restapi");

So, if someone can guide me what I am missing.

Regards,
Pranav

Comment: got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650699/need-docusign-api-endpoint

Answer (score 3):

You can get the information from
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/post-go-live

The production basedURL depend on the which production environment you are connected to.

https://www.docusign.net/restapi

https://na2.docusign.net/restapi

https://na3.docusign.net/restapi

https://eu.docusign.net/restapi